# How to fix cropped shadow in a Horizontal List View in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

When I create a Container with box shadow inside a ListView (scrolls Horizontally), the shadow looks fine, but,  when I add multiple Containers inside the ListView, their shadows(just shadows, not Container) gets cropped at top and bottom.

Please also note that this whole ListView is wrapped under a parent Container.

I tried to increase the height of Parent Container(in which the whole ListView is wrapped), but it increases the height of child Container with its shadow still cropped.

I also tried to give padding to Parent Container but, it still shadow still gets cropped.

Maybe I need to wrap the ListView inside any other Widget which can get the job done without the problem.

```
Container(
  // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 0.0),
  height: 140.0,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
      Container(
        //This is actual custom Card
        width: 340.0,
        height: 140.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              offset: Offset.zero,
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              spreadRadius: 0.0,
            )
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  30.0, 20.0, 25.0, 20.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/leather_boot.png'),
            ),
            Container(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'BadAss Genuine',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 3.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Leather Boots',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 1.5,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Color(0xff643523),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
      Container(
        //This is actual custom Card
        width: 340.0,
        height: 140.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              offset: Offset.zero,
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              spreadRadius: 0.0,
            )
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  30.0, 20.0, 25.0, 20.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/leather_boot.png'),
            ),
            Container(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'BadAss Genuine',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 3.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Leather Boots',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 1.5,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Color(0xff643523),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I expect the ListView to have Containers(as custom Cards) to have proper BoxShadow, but in the actual output, Containers' BoxShadow gets cropped from both Top & Bottom.

Answer (score 50):

As @Zahra wrote,

adding `clipBehavior: Clip.none,` to the `ListView`, solved the problem.

The crop happens only when your widgets exceed the screen size

Answer (score 8):

Okay I found the solution myself.

**Steps to fix the problem**

1. Create several Container(as a card) with some width and with a BoxShadow of Radius 10.0. Lets call it Child Container.
2. Create a ListView with Horizontal scroll axis. Put Child Containers made above in this ListView.
3. Now wrap the ListView inside a new Container(Lets call it Parent Container) to give ListView a height. If you want your Child Containers to be of height 140.0, then make your Parent Container's height 160.0, which includes radius of BoxShadow of 10.0 on top & bottom each(10.0+ 140.0 + 10.0).
4. Now give padding to your ListView of 10.0 on both top & bottom.
5. Problem Solved (Silly Me).

**Sample Code here**

```
Container(
  height: 160.0,
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 340.0,
        // height: 140.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              color: Colors.black12,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  30.0, 20.0, 25.0, 20.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/leather_boot.png'),
            ),
            Container(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'BadAss Genuine',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 3.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Leather Boots',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 1.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Color(0xff643523),
                  ),
                                      SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 110.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 30.0,
                        child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/boot.png'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
      Container(
        //This is actual custom Card
        width: 340.0,
        // height: 140.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              color: Colors.black12,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  30.0, 20.0, 25.0, 20.0),
              child:
                  Image.asset('assets/images/gloves.png'),
            ),
            Container(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Highly Durable',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 3.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Riding Gloves',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 1.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Color(0xff643523),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 110.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 30.0,
                        child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/glove.png'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
      Container(
        //This is actual custom Card
        width: 340.0,
        // height: 140.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              color: Colors.black12,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  30.0, 20.0, 25.0, 20.0),
              child:
                  Image.asset('assets/images/helmet.png'),
            ),
            Container(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'German Hat',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 3.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Riding Helmet',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 1.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Color(0xff643523),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 110.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 30.0,
                        child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/helmeticon.png'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 30.0,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: This will end up in more gap between the ListView and other widgets in the same Column or Row.

Comment: You can use the clip option inside a listView  by setting clip to none : ``clipBehavior: Clip.none``

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the clip Behavior property helped to display shadows. However, this property created big problems: ListView elements began to run over neighboring widgets when scrolling.

I think to solve the problem it is more correct to wrap the list items (widgets with shadows) in a Container with the margin property. This property is created for this purpose. Set the value of the property to the size of the shadow.

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
  child: MyListViewElement ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add these two attributes to solve the issue

```
screenshotController
        .captureFromWidget(
      screenShotWidet(),
      delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 100), // for fetching 
      targetSize: const Size(800, 10000), // this should be max to sycn
    )
```